# Hamiltonian related to Riemann zeta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

using the eigenvstates of the Harmonic oscillator could we give a meaning to the Hamiltonian

$$ H=\log(a.a^{+}+1) $$

here $ a$ and $ a^{+}$ are the creation/anihilation operators with commutation rules $ [a,a^{+}]=1$ are the energies of the Hamiltonian $$ E_{n}=\log(n+1) $$ for $ n\ge 0$. The idea is that the partition function of this system with discrete energies would be the Riemann zeta function

$$ Z(s)= \sum_{n\ge 0 }e^{-sE_{n}}=\zeta(s)$$  with $ s=1/kt$.

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: I believe he's asking whether the Hamiltonian above is meaningful/makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

That system is called [Primon gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primon_gas) (Wikipedia).

The Riemann zeta function also pops up in another field theory context, see [this table](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zeta-functions%20and%20eta-functions%20and%20theta-functions%20and%20L-functions%20--%20table) (nLab).

Also, your use of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ appears flipped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking, as suggested in the comments, if it is possible to define in a rigorous fashion $\ln (N+1)$, where $N$ is the self-adjoint number operator, then the answer is yes.

The spectral theorem allows you to define the function $f(A)$ of a self-adjoint operator $A$, as long as $f$ is measurable wrt the spectral measure of $A$ (and this is the case).

Anyways, this is not the only connection between the bosonic second quantization and number theory (e.g. the prime numbers can be related to the spectrum of certain suitable operators associated with second quantization).